# Why does the blog link at the top of the meta page link to the SE blog and not the Photo.SE blog?

Tags: feature-request, links, blog, meta

Also, there is no top-of-page blog link on the main page.

At the very bottom of the page (after scrolling all the way down), there is a blog link on both the main and meta pages, but the meta one links to the SE blog (like the top link on the same page) and the main page links to the Photo.SE blog.

I find this kind of confusing, and it was difficult to find a link to the Photo.SE blog.

Could we get some consistency, and perhaps make it easier to find the Photo.SE blog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On meta, we link to the Stack Exchange blog because it is more meta-y.  It contains things that affect the sites that people who read meta are more likely to care about or be interested in.

On the main site, we do include a link to the photo community blog *when there has been a post within the last day*.  Space in the header is at a premium, and linking to a blog with stale entries doesn't hold much value, especially when the blog link fights the chat link for visibility.

The last photo blog entry is from a month ago.  I've been poking the people involved in the blog about getting a new post up, perhaps this will help motivate them! (:

Comment: OK, I guess I see the logic in that, except that it seems difficult to find the photo blog, which may be why there are fewer posts?

Comment: Also, only showing the blog link at the top when there has been a post in the last day seems a very short window.  I'm sure many people don't visit every day, and a blog entry that is 1 week old certainly isn't stale to people who only visit a few times a week.